# Get next given day after a month in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

How can I get the *next particular day* after a *month* in c#,
for example if today is `Monday` I need to get the *first* `Monday` after *1 month* from now, but in more generic way, for example if today is `17/11/2021` which is `Wednesday` I need to get the *first* `Wednesday` after a month from now.

I am using this function but it will return for *next week* and not *next month*:

```
public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, DayOfWeek day)
{
    // The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
    int daysToAdd = ((int)day - (int)start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

    return start.AddDays(daysToAdd);
}
```

Comment: What is *after a month*, please? E.g. what is *after a month* for `31 Jan 2020`, `31 Mar 2020`, `30 Apr 2020`? Is it OK just to add `28` (or `35`) days, i.e. add **4** or **5** weeks?

Comment: When you say you want the first day after a month, for instance if you want Wednesday, are you wanting the first Wednesday in the *next* month, or the first Wednesday about a month from the current date like 30ish days away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical month has `30` or `31` days, however, the next same day of week will be after either `28` (`4 * 7`) or `35` (`5 * 7`) days. We need a *compromise*. Let for `February` add `28` days and for all the other months add `35` days:

```
public static DateTime GetSameDayAfterMonth(DateTime start) =>
  start.AddDays((start.AddMonths(1) - start).TotalDays < 30 ? 28 : 35);
```

Sure, you can elaborate other rules: say, when after adding `28` days we are still in the same month (`1 May + 28 days == 29 May`) we should add `35`:

```
public static DateTime GetSameDayAfterMonth(DateTime start) =>
  start.AddDays(start.Month == start.AddDays(28).Month ? 35 : 28);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a month, instead of a week to the start date:

```cs
public static DateTime GetSameDayAfterMonth(DateTime start)
{
    var compare = start.AddMonths(1);
    // The % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
    int daysToAdd = ((int)start.DayOfWeek - (int)compare.DayOfWeek) % 7;
    return compare.AddDays(daysToAdd);
}
```

Example:

```
var dayInNextMonth = GetSameDayAfterMonth(DateTime.Parse("2021-11-17")); // 2021-12-15

var weekday = dayInNextMonth.DayOfWeek; // Wednesday
```